# Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1390

Tags: magento-enterprise, dropdown-attribute

I am trying to use a custom Yes/No attribute to show/hide an element within the Price.phtml file but whenever I add the condition I keep getting this error and I can't understand why since I had it working previously.

Here is what I have added from line 359 of Price.phtml

```
    <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
        <p class="special-price">
            <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
            <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText($_specialPriceStoreLabel['hide_special_price']) == "Yes"): ?>
        <span class="del" style="display: none;"><?php echo $this->__('RRP') ?> <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice, true, false) ?><?php $regularprice =  $_regularPrice; ?></span>
        <?php         $price_diff = $regularprice-$finalPrice;
        $discountPercent = ($price_diff/$regularprice)*100;
        $discountPercent = ceil($discountPercent); ?>
        <span class="discount" style="display: none;">(-<?php echo $discountPercent; ?>%)</span>
            <?php else: ?>
            <span class="del"><?php echo $this->__('RRP') ?> <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice, true, false) ?><?php $regularprice =  $_regularPrice; ?></span>
            <?php         $price_diff = $regularprice-$finalPrice;
            $discountPercent = ($price_diff/$regularprice)*100;
            $discountPercent = ceil($discountPercent); ?>
            <span class="discount">(-<?php echo $discountPercent; ?>%)</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically what I would like to achieve is by adding a new attribute and adding it to the price group I can set whether to display special price on the frontend or not for certain products.

I keep getting this error:

```
function getSource() on a non-object in /*****/*****/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1390
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Comment: could you post your complete error? where is that actually fired? file/line?

Comment: @TobiasZander Thanks for the reply, please see my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is incorrect wich causes the problem:

```
if($_product->getAttributeText($_specialPriceStoreLabel['hide_special_price']) == "Yes")
```

Use like this:

```
if($_product->getHideSpecialPrice())
```

or

```
if($_product->getData('hide_special_price'))
```

And your attribute `hide_special_price` should be **"Used in Product Listing"** and **"Visible on Product View Page on Front-end"** (see attribute edit page).